# Address already in use: JVM_Bind java

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss, ip-address, struts

Some times whenever I restart the application, which is built on
Java,
Struts,
Mysql, and Jboss 4.05 Version
I get the error as **Address already in use: JVM_Bind**

Only fix that I know is to restart the machine and try again, it will work.
Else Some times I do Ctrl-Alt-Del and Stop all the process related to Java, some times this also works.

But what is the exact reason and how can we prevent this problem?

Comment: Sometimes the port ownership lingers and sticks to your Java program even after you close it. However, with Eclipse Java EE, the port binding is removed the moment you except your program

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`Address already in use: JVM_Bind` means that some other application is already listening on the port your current application is trying to bind.

What you need to do is, either change the port for your current application or better just find out the already running application and kill it.

on Linux you can find the application pid by using,

```
netstat -tulpn
```

Comment: How do you  find that in WIndows, I am running my application on Windows

Comment: netstat works on windows too, on console try: netstat -an
for more, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat

Comment: another advice would be not to run application servers on windows.

Otherwise, it might also help not to click on the restart button - but instead to stop, wait 5 seconds, and then start again manually. Sometimes java processes just need a litte time to shut down. Eg if they are busy with a db operation, they tend to keep hanging until that operation is done.

Comment: This answer is good (+1); however, http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/address-already-use-jvm-bind-exception.html goes into a little more detail, particularly regarding Windows.  If you incorporated some of that info, this answer would be even better.

Comment: tulpn is not recognized

Comment: I'll add that I had this happen on an occasion when the ports said to be in conflict were not in fact in use by any other running app. I rebooted the box (Windows) and then the app started, no problem. There were Windows updates "pending a restart". Perhaps something was in an unexpected state. Just sharing this if anyone else ever hits the same situation.

Answer (score 29):

In windows this scenario happens when Eclipse crashes without a clean shutdown it will have the local `Jetty` or `Tomcat` server keep running.
When you reopen Eclipse and try to start server again this will lead to the `Address already in use: JVM_Bind`

You can solve this by opening Task Manager and find the javaw.exe process and ending it.

Then you can restart the server on Eclipse.

[image]

Comment: Super ! Worked for me

Answer (score 25):

On windows, in an elevated cmd/ps

```
net stop winnat
```

then run

```
net start winnat
```

Resets the windows `NAT service` and removes faulty listeners.
This method works for most `cannot listen on this port` errors, like as in Docker, JVM etc.

Comment: This helped for me. I was starting an app in a windows machine and the JVM kept responding with address already in use error, even though there wasn't anything that was using that port. Restarting winnat service fixed the problem.

Answer (score 13):

I usually come across this when the port which the server (I use JBoss) is already in use

Usual suspects

1. Apache Http Server -> Turn down the service if working in windows.
2. IIS -> stop the ISS using
3. Skype -> yea I got skype attaching itself to port 80

To change the port to which JBoss 4.2.x binds itself go to:

```
C:\jboss4.2.2\server\default\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\server.xml
```

here default is the instance of the server
change the port here :

```
Connector port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
```

In the above example the port is bound to 8080

Comment: shutdown skype and run your java application and then bring up skype.

Answer (score 7):

Open command line and type: `netstat -a -o -n` or `tasklist` to see currently running processes.
Find port that related to Java and type: `taskkill /F /PID <your PID number>`.
Click Enter.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that MySql listening on the same port as JBoss?

Is there a port number given in the error message - something like `Address already in use: JVM_Bind:8080`

You can change the port in JBoss server.xml to test this.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness as many may fall in this SO for other reasons than OP's question, here is another info that saved my day :

**TL;DR;**
Check that the port you want to open is not reserved (even though no application has opened it)
On windows :
`netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`

**Explanation :**
At least on windows, another possible cause for the `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind` is that the operating system has "reserved" the port.
If you use the commands from other answer in this topic, they will tell you that no application is listening to the port, yet you cannot open it.

Some windows update [like this one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/february-13-2018-kb4074588-os-build-16299-248-b4e2ca66-dd7a-6fd5-a8f3-dc6683d4922b) reserves range port that can then no longer be claimed by processes.
Though not explicit on the port that can no longer be opened, the update note mentions a command that can help troubleshooting the issue :

`netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`

this will yield a list of port range that are blocked :

```
Protocol tcp Port Exclusion Ranges

Start Port    End Port
----------    --------
5357        5357
49709       49808
49809       49908
49909       50008
50009       50108
50109       50208
50280       50379

* - Administered port exclusions.
```

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer on how to prevent it is that you most likely need to stop JBoss before starting it again.

You should be able to call the "Terminate" button in the Console view to shutdown the server.

Comment: I am starting the JBoss from Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

That error means that the you are trying to create a new `ServerSocket` on a port already in use by another `ServerSocket`. So try to make your application closing all sockets and connections you know about and be sure your application is completely terminated. Also check if there is another proces you launched by your program.

Answer (score 1):

It can be also caused by double definition of port 8080 in ..\tomcat\conf\server.xml :

```
<Connector port="8080"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" debug="0"/>
<Connector port="8080"
           enableLookups="false" address="127.0.0.1" maxParameterCount="30000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try following options for JVM binding exception:

1. start and stop the server. and check the server process ids and kill and stop the server.
2. go to control panel->administrative tool-> service-> check all server and stop all the servers and then start your own server.
3. change the Browser which your using. for example if 
   your using IE ,change it to Mozilla firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too. For me, I couldn't start/stop openfire (it said it was stopped, but everything was still running)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/openfire stop
sudo /etc/init.d/openfire start
```

Also, restarting apache did not help either

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

The errors were inside:

```
/opt/openfire/logs/stderror.log
Error creating server listener on port 5269: Address already in use
Error creating server listener on port 5222: Address already in use
```

The way I fixed this, I had to actually turn off the server inside the admin area for my host.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same on Windows. My solution was to get which port the debug wants to connect to. (In IntelliJ a red rectangle already giving the info: "Error running Tomcat: Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:XXXXX): ... Already in use...")
Let's say XXXXX is the port number.
Then i searched for the problem and the PID in a cmd window:

```
netstat -ano | find "CLOSE_WAIT" | find ":XXXXX"
```

I got the PID number as the last number in the result line. (Let's say YYYY)
Finally:

```
TASKKILL /PID YYYY
```

An extra info: Winscp logged out meanwhile, probably it was causing my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

This recently happen to me when enabling JMX on two running tomcat service within Eclipse. I mistakenly put the same port for each server.

Simply give each jmx remote a different port

Server 1

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000
```

Server 2

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9001
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting the Team Server credentials, most likely those will include some kind of port in the server column.
Like https://wathever.visualstudio.com:443

Go to Windows/Preferences
expand Team then Team Foundation Server
go to Credentials and remove whichever is there.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, even when I'd search with `netstat`, no processes were binding to that port, but I'd still get the "Address already in use" Bind exception.

In this case, going into

Safari -> Preferences -> Privacy -> Manage Website Data... -> finding "localhost" -> Remove

fixes the problem, if there really is no process running with that port. It seems Safari's web cache maintains a reference to the port somehow, and removing that cache frees up the port.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, I use `lsof -i:8080` and I get nothing back, no pid.  Well something has to be taking place.  If this is your case, it could be docker.  By using `docker ps` you can check if you have any old dockers lying around and kill them.  This could be the culprit for a port already in use error.

Answer (score 0):

For me restart did it, for now. The issue was that the port was occupied by another process. Now I need to find out why the port was not free.