# got an issue with Apache Tomcat Application server in eclipse

Tags: tomcat7

I have copied this from my console in eclipse please can anyone help to find the problem:

```
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in   production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Vodafone\Vodafone Mobile Broadband\Optimization Client\;D:\$ Programing\eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32\eclipse;;.
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-7070"]
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1673 ms
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.33
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-7070"]
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 635 ms
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:766)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:712)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-7070"]
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-7070"]
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-7070"]
Dec 07, 2012 5:27:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772701/address-already-in-use-jvm-bind-java this is just 1 example of loads. took 2 seconds to find multiple answers on google. Please do a bit of research into your question first.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you already have some kind of server running on port 8005. Typically it is another instance of Tomcat.

If you are using Windows then you can open a command console (cmd) and type the following:

```
netstat -aon
```

search for port 8005 in the listing and using the PID type the following (replace xxxx with the PID):

```
tasklist /FI "PID eq xxxx"
```

This would list the process that is listening on this port.