# Jboss error startup

Tags: eclipse

please help me to find solution to this error, while I'm trying to start Jboss 7.1.1 ( JEE eclipse )

```
01:41:07,497 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
01:41:07,678 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
01:41:07,726 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
01:41:08,771 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
01:41:08,772 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
01:41:08,783 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
01:41:08,793 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
01:41:08,812 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
01:41:08,819 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
01:41:08,832 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
01:41:08,846 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
01:41:08,854 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
01:41:08,865 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
01:41:08,875 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
01:41:08,906 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
01:41:08,932 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
01:41:08,941 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
01:41:08,980 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.0)
01:41:08,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
01:41:09,017 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
01:41:09,136 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
01:41:09,431 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory D:\ESPRIT\4SIM3\Architecures N-Tiers JEE (4SIM)\S1 (Intro + EJB)\JEE6ToolsEsprit\JEE6ToolsEsprit\Server\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
01:41:09,436 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found firstJB.jar in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called firstJB.jar.dodeploy
01:41:09,587 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
01:41:09,607 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Démarrage de Coyote HTTP/1.1 sur http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8383
01:41:09,619 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.remoting.server.management: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.remoting.server.management: JBAS017112: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9999
    at org.jboss.as.remoting.AbstractStreamServerService.start(AbstractStreamServerService.java:109)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:126) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:52) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpServer(NioXnioWorker.java:287)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamServer(XnioWorker.java:135)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionProvider$ProviderInterface.createServer(RemoteConnectionProvider.java:209)
    at org.jboss.as.remoting.AbstractStreamServerService.start(AbstractStreamServerService.java:101)
    ... 5 more

01:41:09,736 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/mysql]
01:41:09,736 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
01:41:09,752 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.remoting.server.management: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.remoting.server.management: JBAS017112: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9999
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Address already in use: JVM\_Bind java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772701/address-already-in-use-jvm-bind-java)

Answer (score 3):

> org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed
>   to start service jboss.remoting.server.management:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.remoting.server.management: JBAS017112: Address already in use:
>   bind /127.0.0.1:9999

It looks like the address is already bound. I would check that you don't already have another process previously started listening on that port. Kill it and try to start again if it does exist.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows:

Try "netstat -aon" command.
Running this command would list all current processes and the ports (Local Address) using.

Example:

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
 TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       864
 TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
 TCP    127.0.0.1:5432         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2004
 TCP    127.0.0.1:5432         127.0.0.1:49285        ESTABLISHED     2004
```

Find the process with bind address you are having issues with (in your case /127.0.0.1:9999)
Try killing the process using "taskkill /f /pid PID"