# Calling External Web Service via Apache Camel

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel, restful-authentication

I have an external Rest Web Service which returns JSON Object.

Url Pattern: http-://Server_IP:Port/auth/Login.
I would like to capture the json and using camel-jetty for the same.. 
The Problem is that it shows 'Address Already In Use'

Could anyone guide me the exact procedure to use a camel component to achieve the same??

```
    from("jetty://http://ServerIP:8097/ServerReportRest/Auth/login")
            .to("log:INFO");
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that another process is running using the same port 8097. Kill that other process or choose another port for your jetty server.

See [Address already in use: JVM_Bind java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772701/address-already-in-use-jvm-bind-java).