# Error while starting Android Studio: BindException

Tags: android-studio

I am getting this (ref. image) error when launching Android Studio 2.2:

> Internal Error.
>
> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772701/address-already-in-use-jvm-bind-java#2772758

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Address already in use: JVM\_Bind java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772701/address-already-in-use-jvm-bind-java)

Comment: Welcome to SO: In order to solve this problem, we need more information. The question also falls outside the scope of stackoverflow. Please take a look at this information so you get an idea about the scope of this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I resolved the same issue in my windows Android Studio by doing [what I've shared here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640950/13036358)