# Address already in use ["ajp-nio-1099"]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying to run spring mvc application but I am getting this error

```
SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-1099"]
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

I saw posts that address HTTP port problem but in my case it is AJP port problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Address already in use: JVM\_Bind java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772701/address-already-in-use-jvm-bind-java)

Comment: As i said it is not HTTP port problem i tried to change dozen of times it did not help

Comment: Well, have you checked if another application is running on the AJP port? The accepted answer in the duplicate question shows you how to do that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure JMX port and AJP port are not the same